# Approximation ratio for the b-Matching problem

Tags: graph-theory

For an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and a bound on the vertex degree $b: V \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, I am looking into the problem of finding a maximal subset $H$ of $E$, such that each vertex $v\in V$ in the induced subgraph $G[H]$ has degree $\deg_{G[H]}(v)\leq b(v)$. The special case $b \equiv 1$ are matchings.

An interesting question is, how good does the greedy perform (pick edges until you can't add any further ones).

This [book](http://books.google.de/books?id=QhYZuSAb-FIC&pg=PA196#v=onepage&q&f=false) claims (Theorem 3.1), that the greedy gives an approximation ratio of $\dfrac{1}{2}$. To see this they take an arbitrary maximal $b$-Matching $M$ and a maximum $b$-Matching $M^*$ and consider $S=\{v \in V| \text{there are exactly }b(v) \text{ edges of M incident to }v\}$. Then they claim that every edge in $M^*$ must have an endpoint in $S$ as otherwise $M$ would not be maximal.

I have doubts in this claim: For the special case $M=M^*$ it means that a maximum $b$-Matching has not $2$ unsaturated nodes connected via a matching edge, but isn't this a counterexample:
[image]

(red = $M=M^*$, orange=$S$, node labels=$b(v)$)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you - good counterexample! The proof can be fixed though. For example, note that $\frac{|M\setminus M^*|}{|M^*\setminus M|}\leq\frac{|M|}{|M^*|}$, so (after adjusting $b$ appropriately) it suffices to consider the case $M\cap M^*=\emptyset$.